# pusher subscription with React-native, setState update

Tags: javascript, react-native, pusher

I'm trying to implement function with Pusher-JS in a React-native app but having a difficult time to appropriately update the state of a variable in this app.

Out side of main class, I define

```
var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxsome number and code');
```

Inside the main class component, I define a function

```
test() {
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
    console.log('ddddddd');
    channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {

    if (data != null) {
      if (data.message != null){
        console.log(data.message);
        this.setState({
          message_box: data.message
          });
      }
    }  
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

and I put test() under render() function like the below.

```
render() {
    this.what();
    ...
```

The app freezes when I push a text message (from pusher testing server) to 'test_channel'(in the mobile app). When I see the log in Chrome console, the console.log('dddddd') and console.log(data.message) keeps being scrolled down very quickly ( seems like test() is re-rendered a lot ).

I tried to take test() outside of render() but I don't know how to separately put and update the state variable outside of main component.

Is there way that I can stabilize this function or way to setState outside of main component ( this )?

Please share any idea with me!

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `test` function being called every time on render? Pusher#bind adds a new callback to its registry whenever it gets called. It could be that whenever a message comes in, this function is being called multiple times, leading to more callbacks in the registry.

Perhaps try binding to an event once, perhaps in `getInitialState`?

Comment: wow it works. So, if I got your point correctly, when a function is stated in getInitialSate (or constructor in my case), it is one time initialized and whenever a new call back added, then test function is triggered => setState is only one time activated => render again and this rendering has no impact on "test" function since it is isolated right? (: Thanks for your help!!